# How can I update a specific nested item in my reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a reducer with the following structure:

```
{
    "id": 8,
    "location_name": "Some place",
    "lat": "nn.nnnnnn",
    "lng": "-nn.nnnnn",
    "review_count": 3,
    "score_avg": 3.00,
    "reviews": [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "userId": 1,
            "userName": "JohnDoe",
            "body": "Lorem Ipsum.",
            "score": null,
            "likes": 2,
            "liked": true,
            "review_pic": null
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "userId": 1,
            "userName": "JohnDoe",
            "body": "Lorem Ipsum.",
            "score": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "liked": false,
            "review_pic": null
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "userId": 4,
            "userName": "JohnDoe",
            "body": "Lorem Ipsum.",
            "score": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "liked": false,
            "review_pic": null
        }
    ]
}
```

On the other hand, I have an action creator that returns an ID. I am trying to grab this ID to change liked to true and set likes+1 but the nested nature of this reducer's state is tripping me off.

EDIT: here's what I've been trying with my reducer with no luck:

```
import {GET_REVIEWS, CLEAR_REVIEWS, LIKE} from './reviewTypes';

const initialState = [];

const reviewReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_REVIEWS:
            return action.payload;
        case LIKE:
           const reviews = state.reviews.map(review => {
               if(review.id === action.payload) {
                   return {
                       ...review,
                       liked: true,
                       likes: review.likes++
                   }
               } else {
                   return review;
               }
           });
           return {
               ...state,
               reviews
           }
        case CLEAR_REVIEWS:
            return [];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reviewReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I iterate over array.reviews with [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for finding the review with the desired id. If I found it than I increment the likes and set liked on true,

```js
function updateLike(id, array) {
    array.reviews.some(review => {
        if (review.id==id) {
            review.likes++;
            review.liked = true;
            return true;
        }
    });
}


let array = {
    "id": 8,
    "location_name": "Some place",
    "lat": "nn.nnnnnn",
    "lng": "-nn.nnnnn",
    "review_count": 3,
    "score_avg": 3.00,
    "reviews": [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "userId": 1,
            "userName": "JohnDoe",
            "body": "Lorem Ipsum.",
            "score": null,
            "likes": 2,
            "liked": true,
            "review_pic": null
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "userId": 1,
            "userName": "JohnDoe",
            "body": "Lorem Ipsum.",
            "score": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "liked": false,
            "review_pic": null
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "userId": 4,
            "userName": "JohnDoe",
            "body": "Lorem Ipsum.",
            "score": null,
            "likes": 0,
            "liked": false,
            "review_pic": null
        }
    ]
};

updateLike(15, array);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to obtain the element with a specific `id`.

```js
const data = { "id": 8, "location_name": "Some place", "lat": "nn.nnnnnn", "lng": "-nn.nnnnn", "review_count": 3, "score_avg": 3.00, "reviews": [ { "id": 14, "userId": 1, "userName": "JohnDoe", "body": "Lorem Ipsum.", "score": null, "likes": 2, "liked": true, "review_pic": null }, { "id": 15, "userId": 1, "userName": "JohnDoe", "body": "Lorem Ipsum.", "score": null, "likes": 0, "liked": false, "review_pic": null }, { "id": 13, "userId": 4, "userName": "JohnDoe", "body": "Lorem Ipsum.", "score": null, "likes": 0, "liked": false, "review_pic": null } ] };
let id = 13;
let obj = data.reviews.find(x => x.id === id);
if(obj) obj.liked = true;
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a reducer on that one, because u have only one array and you should be fine with useState, this code should work for you.

```
const onItemLike = (itemID) => {
          setState(state.map(x => {
               if(reviews.id === itemID)
               return {...x, liked: true, likes: state.reviews[x].likes+1}
          }))
     }
```